# Firebase | Reading data from Firebase returns "undefined", but console.log shows precise result

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

EDIT: I'm new to Stack, but why was my earlier thread locked? It just said "similar thread is found somewhere else" and the thread wasn't at all similar.

I am currently trying to update my own little personal weight tracker using Firebase and React Native. However, whenever I log `DataSnapshot.val()` I receive the input `22`, which is perfect. But when I return the very same value I receive `Undefined`.

I tried both `get()` and `onValue()` with the same results. The path is correct, since I get the correct data using console.log.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=2

I tried following the above documentation. But is it updated? `snapshot` is currently `DataSnapshot`?

**Firebase:**

```js
const readWeight = (database, userId) => {
  get(ref(database, `users/${userId}/weight`)).then((DataSnapshot) => {
    try {
      if (DataSnapshot.exists()) {
        console.log(
          `Weight found. Current weight is: ${DataSnapshot.val()} kg`
        );
        return DataSnapshot.val();
      } else {
        console.log("Weight wasn't found");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
};
```

HomeScreen.js

```js
// Modules
import { react, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View, TextInput, Image } from "react-native";
import { LogOutButton } from "../Components/LogOutButton";
import { auth, writeUserData, database, readWeight } from "../firebase";

// Stylesheet
import { styles } from "../Stylesheet/Stylesheet";

export const HomeScreen = () => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  let currentUserWeight = readWeight(database, user.uid);


  console.log("Current Weight: ", currentUserWeight);


  return (
    <View style={styles.profileMain}>
      <View style={styles.profileInfoContainer}>

        <View style={styles.HOME__profileWeightContainer}>

          <Text style={styles.HOME__profileWeightText}>
            Last Weight: {currentUserWeight}
          </Text>

        </View>
      </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, and the `return DataSnapshot.val()` runs way after you actually call `readWeight(database, user.uid)`. Adding some logging is probably the best way to see that flow.

The solution is to store the weight in the state of your component with the `useState` hook.

```
export const HomeScreen = () => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  // 
  let { currentUserWeight, setCurrentUserWeight } = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = get(ref(database, `users/${userId}/weight`)).then((DataSnapshot) => {
      if (DataSnapshot.exists()) {
        setCurrentUserWeight(DataSnapshot.val());
      }
    });  
    return () => unsubscribe();
  , []}
  // 

  return (
    <View style={styles.profileMain}>
      <View style={styles.profileInfoContainer}>

        <View style={styles.HOME__profileWeightContainer}>

          <Text style={styles.HOME__profileWeightText}>
            Last Weight: {currentUserWeight}
          </Text>

        </View>
      </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```